# Why does 12.04 64-bit installer fail to find root fs and panic?

Tags: installation, command-line, ubiquity

I bought a new laptop with a Linpus Linux bootup. I can't install ubuntu 12.04 64-bit.  I don't know why. It says there's no prefix and then shows a new set of error messages:

"Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
Pid: 1, comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 3.2.0-23-generic #36-Ubuntu"

specs:
acer 4755G
2nd gen Intel i7
8GB ram

Comment: Specifications for the laptop please?

Comment: specs: acer 4755G, 2nd gen Intel i7, 8GB ram

Comment: How are installing Ubuntu?

Comment: through DVD which I burned from an iso

Comment: At what point you get the error?

Comment: @izx thanks ...@mitch after booting from the installer and getting the "no prefix" message

Comment: do an [MD5Sum](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) on the ISO

Comment: the MD5sum is correct

Answer (score 0):

is the laptop booting from the live cd? 
If yes than try to format you whole hard disk with gparted. As soon the hard disk is empty try to install Ubuntu again.

Greetings

Comment: there is no live CD but it says that it's booting from linpus linux  (no graphics, just terminal)

Comment: how can I format with gparted?

Comment: there's no live CD but the current bootup is Linpus Linux LiveCD Edition v9.2

Comment: I already installed ubuntu after emptying the hard disk but same errors were given